# In Excel, I need to get an exact match

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm using the following code to find the first instance of a partial string match, but I am not getting exactly the match I want.

```
=IF(
 ISNUMBER(INDEX(veneerData,1,AGGREGATE(15,7,COLUMN(veneerData)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B119,veneerData))),1))),
 IF(
  ISNUMBER(INDEX(HPLData,1,AGGREGATE(15,7,COLUMN(HPLData)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B119,HPLData))),1))),
  MIN(
   INDEX(veneerData,1,AGGREGATE(15,7,COLUMN(veneerData)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B119,veneerData))),1)),
   INDEX(HPLData,1,AGGREGATE(15,7,COLUMN(HPLData)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B119,HPLData))),1))
  ),
  INDEX(veneerData,1,AGGREGATE(15,7,COLUMN(veneerData)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B119,veneerData))),1))
 ),
 IF(
  ISNUMBER(INDEX(HPLData,1,AGGREGATE(15,7,COLUMN(HPLData)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B119,HPLData))),1))),
  INDEX(HPLData,1,AGGREGATE(15,7,COLUMN(HPLData)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B119,HPLData))),1)),
  ""
 )
)
```

If I'm looking for `-033`, then I want that to ONLY match cells where the end of the string is `-033`. For example, if a cell contains `3447-033-128` I'm getting a match, but I don't want to match to that. If a cell contains `3447-128-033`, I DO want to match with that cell.

Also, I cannot use a VBA solution as I don't have any experience with VBA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for a partial match based on the last four characters of the string being `-033` I would use something like this and keep it simple. This assumes your data is in A1, and I figure for the true statement you can set it to whatever you want. I'm focusing on how to get the formula to read the last 4 characters for you.

```
=IF(RIGHT(A1,4)="-033",[Do something],"")
```

Comment: I need to look in an array of cells, not just in one cell.

Comment: @JustinWhite then replace `ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B119,HPLData))` with `RIGHT(HPLData,4) = B119`